# How to stack two scrollable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs stacked on top of each other and would like to able to show the content of each at a time by clicking on a tab/button. I also want them to be scrollable as there is a lot of information in each div. I already know how to alternate the appearance of the divs using some jQuery, but it seems that the divs are interfering with each other. At the moment scrolling only works if I remove one of the divs.

```js
window.onload = function () {
 'use strict';
  
  //tabs on right side of popup boxes
 var aventureTab = document.getElementById('massiveAdventure');
 var massartTab = document.getElementById('massArt');
  
 //text information
 var adventureText = document.getElementById('adventureText');

 var artText = document.getElementById('massArt');

 massartTab.onclick = function () {
  TweenMax.to(adventureText, 0, {
   opacity: 0,
  })
  TweenMax.to(artText, 0.5, {
   opacity: 1,
  })
 }
  
 }
```

```css
.text {
  width: 565px;
  height: 420px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  margin: 2rem 0 0 7.1rem;
  padding: 40px 60px 0 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.text::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0 !important
}

.text {
  background-colour: grey;
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
}

#adventureText {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

#artText {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!--Critical Mass/Massive-->
   <div class="col-sm" id="aboutSection">

    <div class="text" id="adventureText">
     <h1 class="display-3">Critical Massive<br> Adventure</h1>
     <br>
     <p>Critical Massive Adventure is an epic one-day festival and series of artist-led workshops that will explore the fantastic and ephemeral world of storytelling, performance, role playing games, imagination and adventure through the lens of contemporary art.
      <br>
      <br>On August 17th, Port Hope-based non profit arts organization, Critical Mass: A Centre for Contemporary Art, invites you to enjoy adventure, music, live performance, contemporary art, food, fun and getting to play D&amp;D, dress up and be weird in a safe, inclusive space with your friends!
      <br>
      <br> Click on each icon in our legend for more information about what’s happening at the festival, to check out our pre-festival workshops, to register for our epic Community Dungeons & Dragons Tournament, and to contact us if you would like to get involved!
      <br>
      <br> There is most certainly a role for you in our critical massive adventure.
     </p>
    </div>

    <div class="text" id="artText">
 <h1 class="display-3">Critical Mass Art</h1>

 <p>Critical Mass is a small volunteer run contemporary arts organization based in Port Hope, Ontario. </p>

 <p>We do not receive operating grants or government funding. We rely on small project grants, and corporate sponsorships to help cover the cost of expenses such as artist fees, materials and logistical items needed to run our programs and festivals. This year, we are feeling the pinch of cutbacks to these smaller grant streams. So, we also rely on private support from people like you to make our programs possible! We believe that art is for everyone and should be accessible.</p>

 <p>We also believe that artists should be paid a professional wage.</p>

 <p>So we strive to provide free or low cost participation in our programs &amp/or admission to our exhibits and special events.</p>

 <p>We work hard to do this because we believe anyone should have the opportunity to participate in or experience the arts and its many benefits such as social inclusion, health and mental wellness.</p>

</div>

    <svg id="About" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1399.26 818.51" width="900" height="475">
     <defs>
      <style>
       .cls-1,
       .cls-3 {
        fill: #fff;
       }
       
       .cls-2 {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: AlbertText-Bold, Albert Text;
       }
       
       .cls-3,
       .cls-4 {
        stroke: #1a1a1a;
       }
       
       .cls-3,
       .cls-4,
       .cls-5 {
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
       }
       
       .cls-3 {
        stroke-width: 8px;
       }
       
       .cls-4,
       .cls-5 {
        fill: none;
        stroke-width: 5px;
       }
       
       .cls-5 {
        stroke: #000;
       }
      </style>
     </defs>
     <title>About</title>
     <g id="massiveAdventure">
      <g id="tab1">
       <polygon class="cls-1" points="1088.59 140.38 1088.26 53.38 1396.29 52.49 1362.66 98.1 1394.98 140.49 1088.59 140.38" />
       <path d="M1749.3,204l-31.19,42.3-1.33,1.81,1.36,1.79,29.8,39.09-301.87-.11-.32-84L1749.3,204m6-3-312.51.9.34,90L1754,292l-33.47-43.91,34.72-47.1Z" transform="translate(-355.99 -150)" />
      </g>
      <text class="cls-2" transform="translate(1152.84 91.16) scale(1.05 1)">Critical Massive
       <tspan x="27.71" y="28">Adventure</tspan>
      </text>
     </g>

     <g id="massArt">
      <g id="tab2">
       <polygon class="cls-1" points="859.75 159.2 1166.2 157.57 1129.92 204.63 1161.75 247 859.6 247.34 859.75 159.2" />
       <path d="M1519.13,309.09l-33.71,43.72-1.4,1.81,1.37,1.82,29.35,39.06-297.65.34.15-85.15,301.89-1.6m6.12-3-311,1.66-.15,91.14,306.65-.36-33-43.85,37.46-48.59Z" transform="translate(-355.99 -150)" />
      </g>
      <g id="cmArt">
       <text class="cls-2" transform="translate(942.63 208.22) rotate(0.31) scale(0.88 1)">Critical Mass Art</text>
      </g>
     </g>

     <g id="contentBox">
      <polygon class="cls-3" points="10.51 54.5 67.01 4 1061.01 4 1096.01 47.5 1105.01 770.5 1063.01 814.5 42.01 810.5 4.01 761.5 10.51 54.5" />
      <path class="cls-4" d="M368.62,275.18c18.52-58.12,60.5-103.55,129.69-119.86" transform="translate(-355.99 -150)" />
      <path class="cls-4" d="M482.4,961.1c-58.12-18.52-103.55-60.5-119.86-129.7" transform="translate(-355.99 -150)" />
      <path class="cls-4" d="M1336.54,961.1c58.12-18.52,103.55-60.5,119.86-129.7" transform="translate(-355.99 -150)" />
      <path class="cls-4" d="M1450.31,276.18c-18.52-58.12-60.49-103.55-129.69-119.86" transform="translate(-355.99 -150)" />
      <line class="cls-4" x1="1072.01" y1="80" x2="1072.01" y2="747" />
      <line class="cls-4" x1="36.01" y1="77" x2="37.01" y2="750" />
     </g>
    </svg>

   </div>
```

Comment: There's an issue with your example code, please update. You mentioned JS, might need to include that alse.

Comment: Here's the JS. I realized that the first information fades off but the second does not fade on. `massartTab.onclick = function () {
  TweenMax.to(adventureText, 0, {
   opacity: 0,
  })
  TweenMax.to(artText, 0.5, {
   opacity: 1,
  })
 }`

Comment: Please add your JS to your post. Thank you. Also, make sure the Stack Snippet in your post has the correct HTML. It looks like there may be a missing closing tag.

Comment: I've updated and included some of the text content. Can you see what the problem could be?

Comment: Code still isn't working, but why can't you just set the div you don't want to show to `display: none` until you want to show it?

Comment: Looks like you have a third-party JS library that you have not included that is a part of your code. Please include that and make sure you've properly replicated your problem. Thanks